# Test if a post exists by category and date

Tags: functions, permalinks, get-posts

I would like to check outside of the loop, if a certain post exists in a specific category and from a specific date.

The function `get_posts()` -- if I get it right -- allows me to check, if there are posts in a specific category, but does not allow to test, if there is one on a specific date.

The other way I tried is by testing the spefic URL by using the permalink. The permalink has the format: `http://www.homepage.de/yyyy/mm/dd/?cat=id`. But this URL is valid anyway, if it shows a post or the message "Nothing found." So I can't check the URL for a 404 or something.

Now I ran out of ideas? Any help?

Thanks in advance and all the best, Marius

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use `wp_query`, which gives you a lot more flexibility to custom query.

As your requirement is only to check if there are posts with a particular category and date you can write a custom function and can use it anywhere to check it.

Use the code below in the active theme's **`functions.php`** file

```
function check_post_cat_date( $post_type = 'post', $category = 'uncategorized', $published_on = '12-31-2012' ) {
// Use the date format as (mm-dd-yyyy) else change accordingly
$date = explode( '-', $published_on );
$args = array(
    'post_type'     => $post_type,
    'category_name' => $category,
    'monthnum'      => (int) $date[0],
    'day'           => (int) $date[1],
    'year'          => (int) $date[2],
);

$the_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

return count( $the_posts->posts );
```

}

And if you are using version 3.7 or above you can use the **[date_query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters)**

Now you can use this function to check the number of posts it returns.

You can use it in anywhere, something like below:--

```
$post_type = 'post';
$category = 'uncategorized';
$published_on = '10-3-2013';
$user_query = check_post_cat_date( $post_type, $category, $published_on );
if ( $user_query ) {
    // Do something
    echo 'There are ' . $user_query . 'post(s) with category: ' . $category . ' published on ' . $published_on;
} else {
    // Do something else
    echo 'There are no posts with category: ' . $category . ' published on ' . $published_on;
}
```

Comment: Why wouldn't `get_posts()` work with date arguments? Other than few edge cases it's identical to using `WP_Query`, which it wraps.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the date arguments, let me edit the answer

Comment: @Marius If this works for you. can you accept the answer? It will definitely help others looking for the solution to a similar question :)